# Copy numpy column from 2D array into another numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array called indi:

```
indi = npArray = np.array( 
        [[1, 1, 'A', 10], 
          [4, 1 ,'A', 0], 
          [7, 2 ,'A', 3],
          [2, 2 ,'A', 4],
          [6, 2 ,'B', 9],
          [5, 2 ,'B', 7],
          [5, 1 ,'B', 12],
          [5, 1 ,'B', 4],
          [5, 2 ,'C', 9],
          [5, 1 ,'C', 3],
          [5, 1 ,'C', 4],
          [5, 2 ,'C', 7]])

type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I created another numpy array called rebalance using:

```
num_rows, num_cols = df.shape    
rebalance=np.zeros((num_rows,1))
```

I am trying to copy the 4th element of each row from indi into rebalance so the output would look like:

```
[[ 10.]
 [ 0.]
 [ 3.]
 [ 4.]
 [ 9.]
 [ 7.]
 [ 12.]
 [ 4.]
 [ 9.]
 [ 3.]
 [ 4.]
 [ 7.]]

type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I have a method to do this:

```
for i in range(num_rows):
    rebalance[i,0] = indi.pnl[i,3]
```

but it's very slow. Is there a faster way to do this? I'd also like (after I have manipulated rebalance to write rebalance back to the same place in indi. So say I manipulated rebalance to be:

```
[[ 99.]
 [ 67.]
 [ 47.]
 [ 37.]
 [ 86.]
 [ 47.]
 [ 33.]
 [ 63.]
 [ 38.]
 [ 39.]
 [ 92.]
 [ 83.]]

type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

I would like indi to look like:

```
[['1' '1' 'A' '99']
 ['4' '1' 'A' '67']
 ['7' '2' 'A' '47']
 ['2' '2' 'A' '37']
 ['6' '2' 'B' '86']
 ['5' '2' 'B' '47']
 ['5' '1' 'B' '33']
 ['5' '1' 'B' '63']
 ['5' '2' 'C' '38']
 ['5' '1' 'C' '39']
 ['5' '1' 'C' '92']
 ['5' '2' 'C' '83']]

type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: Your statement "I'd also like" is missing a closing bracket in the parenthetical clause, and thus does not make much sense.

Comment: Hi Stacey. Could you respond to the above point from June? I wonder if you meant "I'd also like `(`" i.e. a literal bracket character, not an opening parenthetical statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
indi = np.array( 
    [[1, 1, 'A', 10], 
     [4, 1 ,'A', 0], 
     [7, 2 ,'A', 3],
     [2, 2 ,'A', 4],
     [6, 2 ,'B', 9],
     [5, 2 ,'B', 7],
     [5, 1 ,'B', 12],
     [5, 1 ,'B', 4],
     [5, 2 ,'C', 9],
     [5, 1 ,'C', 3],
     [5, 1 ,'C', 4],
     [5, 2 ,'C', 7]]
)

num_rows, num_cols = indi.shape    
rebalance=np.zeros((num_rows,1))

def slow(indi, rebalance, num_rows):
    for i in range(num_rows):
        rebalance[i,0] = indi[i,3]
    return rebalance

def aBitFaster(indi, rebalance, num_rows):
    rebalance[:,0] = indi[:,3]
    return rebalance

print('\ntiming \'slow\'')
%timeit slow(indi, rebalance, num_rows)

print('\ntiming \'aBitFaster\'')
%timeit aBitFaster(indi, rebalance, num_rows)

print(
    '\nslow(indi, rebalance, num_rows) == '
    'aBitFaster(indi, rebalance, num_rows) = '
    f'\n{(aBitFaster(indi, rebalance, num_rows) == slow(indi, rebalance, num_rows)).all()}'
)

indi[:,3] = np.array(
    [[ 99.],
     [ 67.],
     [ 47.],
     [ 37.],
     [ 86.],
     [ 47.],
     [ 33.],
     [ 63.],
     [ 38.],
     [ 39.],
     [ 92.],
     [ 83.],]
).flatten()

print(f'\nindi = \n{indi}')
```

outputs:

```
timing 'slow'
100000 loops, best of 5: 7.82 µs per loop

timing 'aBitFaster'
The slowest run took 5.59 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 5: 6.02 µs per loop

slow(indi, rebalance, num_rows) == aBitFaster(indi, rebalance, num_rows) = 
True

indi = 
[['1' '1' 'A' '99.0']
 ['4' '1' 'A' '67.0']
 ['7' '2' 'A' '47.0']
 ['2' '2' 'A' '37.0']
 ['6' '2' 'B' '86.0']
 ['5' '2' 'B' '47.0']
 ['5' '1' 'B' '33.0']
 ['5' '1' 'B' '63.0']
 ['5' '2' 'C' '38.0']
 ['5' '1' 'C' '39.0']
 ['5' '1' 'C' '92.0']
 ['5' '2' 'C' '83.0']]
```